# OpenGL Rotation with quaternions not working

Tags: opengl, math, rotation, transformation, quaternions

I am trying to make a cube rotate around fixed axes using quaternions. Here is the code i have produced, using my quaternions :

```
            glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX );
        Quaternion rot1;
        Quaternion rot2;
        rot1.FromAxis(Vector3(1.0,0.0,0.0),angleY);
        rot2.FromAxis(Vector3(0.0,1.0,0.0),angleX);
        rot1.normalise();
        rot2.normalise();
        QAccumulative = QAccumulative * rot1;
        QAccumulative = QAccumulative * rot2;


        Matrix4 mat;
        mat = QAccumulative.getMatrix();

        angleY = 0;
        angleX = 0;
        glMultMatrixf(mat.get());
```

Do you think my code isn't correct, my cube appears to be infinitly big, compared to withouth this pice of code.

EDIT :

After getting some help it turns out that normalizing QAcc makes it identity, but normalizing rot1 and rot2 makes QAcc unstable, here is my normalize method :

```
      void Quaternion::normalise()
{
    // Don't normalize if we don't have to
    float mag2 = w * w + x * x + y * y + z * z;
    if (fabs(mag2) > TOLERANCE && fabs(mag2 - 1.0f) > TOLERANCE) {
        float mag = sqrt(mag2);
        w /= mag;
        x /= mag;
        y /= mag;
        z /= mag;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Here is my FromAxis code :

```
void Quaternion::FromAxis(const Vector3 &v, float angle)
{
    float sinAngle;
    angle *= 0.5f;
    Vector3 vn(v);
    vn.normalize();

    sinAngle = sin(angle);

    x = (vn.x * sinAngle);
    y = (vn.y * sinAngle);
    z = (vn.z * sinAngle);
    w = cos(angle);
}
```

Comment: How is QAccumulative declared and initialized? Is it really useful to set mat to the identity if you are going to overwrite it afterward?

Comment: QAccumulative is declared this way :QAccumulative.FromAxis(Vector3(0.0,0.0,0.0),0);
I thought it would be important to initialize it (its a habit), but as you said i am overwriting it so it is not useful.

Comment: Then that should not be the error. You can try to replace the normalizations of the rot quaternions for the normalization of QAccumulative, but that should change nothing, the norm of the quaternions is not that unstable.

Comment: Well that actually solved a part of the problem, my cube is back to the normal size but it won't rotate when the rotation is applied :D. It did move before this change.

Comment: May that be due to `angleY = 0; angleX = 0;`?

Comment: No because it moved before, plus the rotation is calculated before resetting to 0. Normalizing the QAcc seems to have cancel the rotation

Comment: It actually turns out that normalizing QAcc makes it Identity, but normalizing rot1 and rot2 make it unstable, so it may just come from my normilze method.

Comment: If `QAccumulative` is normalized before, it should not be necessary to normalize it after the rotation. As LutzL said, a quaternion's norm is not that unstable that this simple operation would become visible as a scaling. Is this a one-time operation or do you do this every frame?

Comment: i do it every frame, should i try to do it only if there is a change ? I still have to make the rotation every frame anyway

Comment: If you set `angleX` to 0, it will be zero for subsequent frames and there will be no rotation any more. What value does `TOLERANCE` have? What happens if you normalize a pure rotation quaternion? It should not be changed. Rotation quaternions are unit quaternions.

Comment: TOLERANCE  equals to 0.00001f, i have made a couple of checks, at the beginning after initializing my QAcc, it appears that several values are NaN, but all my values are floats, i do not understand where that could come from.

Comment: Then show your `FromAxis` code. You probably try to normalize the zero-vector.

Comment: Here is my FromAxis code.

Comment: As I said, you're normalizing the zero-vector. First make a check, if the vector can be normalized.

Comment: I was indeed, Thanks very much for your help, i am going to upload the working code as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was indeed normalizing vectors without checking them, adding a tolerance threshold resolved my problem.

Thanks everyone for the help.